# NoSuchMethodError when hive.execution.engine value its tez

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I am using **hive 1.0.0** and **apache tez 0.4.1**
When I configure hive to use tez I get an exception.

In **hive-site.xml** when the **hive.execution.engine** value is `mr` its works fine. But if I set it to `tez` I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tez.mapreduce.hadoop.MRHelpers.updateEnvBasedOnMRAMEnv(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/util/Map;)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.open(TezSessionState.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.open(TezSessionState.java:122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:454)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:626)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:570)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved myself....
i just upgraded the version of tez from 0.4.1 to 0.5.2.
i just heard that tez 0.4.1 had some problems when integrating with hive.